# Optimizing large Excel report

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a problem with generation of my report. Data is read from other sheet in report. Most time is wasted on execution of `LineColor()` and `LineGroup()`. Those operations are based on hierarchy, which is copied and pasted into cells parallel to every row.

> ```
> CoreElementCode   CategoryCode    SubcategoryCode BMCCode ProductId
> 1             30              167             1307    1000152
> 1             30              167             1307    1000152
> 1             30              167             1307    1307
> 1             30              167             1307    1307
> 1             30              167             167     167
> 1             30              167             167     167
> 1             30              30              30      30
> 1             30              30              30      30
> 1             10              101             1014    1000112
> 1             10              101             1014    1000112
> 1             10              101             1014    1014
> 1             10              101             1014    1014
> 1             10              101             1013    1000142
> 1             10              101             1013    1000142
> 1             10              101             1013    1013
> 1             10              101             1013    1013
> 1             10              101             1008    1000122
> 1             10              101             1008    1000122
> 1             10              101             1008    1008
> 1             10              101             1008    1008
> 1             10              101             101     101
> 1             10              101             101     101
> 1             10              100             1306    1000132
> 1             10              100             1306    1000132
> ```

I'am looking for advice on how to make this code faster. Current generation (with 22 thousands rows in `Data_Load` spreadsheet) takes 2 hours.

```
Option Explicit
Public ReportWeek As String

Sub CreateReport()


Load_Data
ReportWeek = Sheets("Headers").Cells(24, 1).Value
Sheets("Category_Sales").Activate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotCache.Refresh

Cells(12, 2).Value = "1"
Cells(12, 3).Value = "2"
Cells(12, 4).Value = "3"
Cells(12, 5).Value = "4"
Cells(12, 6).Value = "5"
Cells(12, 18).Value = "1"
Cells(12, 19).Value = "2"
Cells(12, 20).Value = "3"
Cells(12, 21).Value = "4"
Cells(12, 22).Value = "5"


Cells(12, 2).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(2, 1).Value
Cells(12, 3).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(3, 1).Value
Cells(12, 4).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(4, 1).Value
Cells(12, 5).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(5, 1).Value
Cells(12, 6).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(6, 1).Value
Cells(12, 18).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(2, 1).Value
Cells(12, 19).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(3, 1).Value
Cells(12, 20).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(4, 1).Value
Cells(12, 21).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(5, 1).Value
Cells(12, 22).Value = Sheets("Headers").Cells(6, 1).Value



    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("CoreElementCode")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("CategoryCode")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("SubcategoryCode")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 4
    End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("BMCCode")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 5
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("ProductID")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 6
    End With

Dim rng As Range
Dim MaxLineNumber As Integer

'Column with LineOrder
'Set rng = Worksheets("Data").Range("O1:O25000")
'Find max LineOrder(line number)
Dim nonEmptyRowsNumber As Long
Dim WorkRange As Range

nonEmptyRowsNumber = Worksheets("Data_Load").UsedRange.Columns("O").Rows.Count
Set WorkRange = Worksheets("Data_Load").Range("O2:O" & nonEmptyRowsNumber)

MaxLineNumber = Application.Max(WorkRange)


Range("B13:F" & MaxLineNumber + 1).Select 'wyzej wstawione GMH, pole po polu
Selection.Copy
Range("BL13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("CoreElementCode"). _
Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("CategoryCode"). _
Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("SubcategoryCode"). _
Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("BMCCode"). _
Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("ProductID"). _
Orientation = xlHidden


LineColor (MaxLineNumber)
LineGroup (MaxLineNumber)

Columns("BL:BP").Select 'kasowanie pól z GMH
Selection.Delete

Sheets("Category_Sales").PivotTables("SalesCategory").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="E:\Reports\Main\[MPF_Sales.xlsb]Data_Load!C1:C19", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)


Sheets("Category_Sales").PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Category_Sales").PivotTables("SalesCategory").SaveData = True
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False


Sheets("Category_Sales").Columns("A").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft

Cells(10, 2).Select

SaveXls


End Sub


Sub LineColor(MaxLineNumber As Integer)

Dim CellId As Range
Dim k As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim oColor


' kolorowanie na czarno
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:AV" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
k = CellId.Column
r = CellId.Row
Cells(r, k).Font.Color = 1
Cells(r, k).Font.Bold = False
Next CellId

Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
k = CellId.Column
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 64).Value = "-1" Then 'Store Sales
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 255, 204)
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Font.Bold = True
    ElseIf Cells(r, 64).Value = Cells(r, 65).Value And Cells(r, 65).Value = Cells(r, 66).Value And Cells(r, 64) <> "" Then 'Core Element
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(214, 225, 238)
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Font.Bold = True
    ElseIf Cells(r, 64).Value <> Cells(r, 65).Value And Cells(r, 65).Value = Cells(r, 66).Value Then 'Category
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
    ElseIf Cells(r, 65).Value <> Cells(r, 66).Value And Cells(r, 66).Value = Cells(r, 67).Value Then 'Subcategory
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    ElseIf Cells(r, 66).Value <> Cells(r, 67).Value And Cells(r, 67).Value = Cells(r, 68).Value Then 'BMC
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
    Else
            Range("A" & r & ":AV" & r).Interior.Color = xlNone 'Product
    End If

Next CellId





End Sub

Sub SaveXls()

Dim ReportPath As String
Dim ReportName As String

    Workbooks("MPF_NL_CategorySales.xlsm").Sheets("Category_Sales").Activate
    ReportPath = "E:\Reports_DART\Temp"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Data_Load").Delete
    Sheets("Headers").Delete

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        ReportPath & "\MPF_Weekly_CategorySales_" & ReportWeek & ".xlsb", FileFormat:= _
        xlExcel12, CreateBackup:=False

    Application.Quit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub LineGroup(MaxLineNumber As Integer)

Dim CellId As Range
Dim k As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim oColor

Worksheets("Category_Sales").Activate
Rows("5:" & MaxLineNumber + 5).Select
Selection.ClearOutline
'
k = 13
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 64).Value = "-1" Then
            k = k + 1
    ElseIf Cells(r, 64).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 64).Value And Cells(r, 64).Value <> "" Then
            Rows(k & ":" & r - 1).Rows.Group
            k = r + 1
    End If

Next CellId

k = 13
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 65).Value = Cells(r, 64).Value Then
            k = k + 1
    ElseIf Cells(r, 65).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 65).Value And Cells(r, 65).Value <> "" Then
            Rows(k & ":" & r - 1).Rows.Group
            k = r + 1

    End If

Next CellId
'

k = 13
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 66).Value = Cells(r, 65).Value Then
            k = k + 1
    ElseIf Cells(r, 66).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 66).Value And Cells(r, 66).Value <> "" Then
            Rows(k & ":" & r - 1).Rows.Group
            k = r + 1

    End If

Next CellId
'

k = 13
Set oColor = Worksheets("Category_Sales").Range("A13:A" & MaxLineNumber + 13)
For Each CellId In oColor.Cells
r = CellId.Row

    If Cells(r, 67).Value = Cells(r, 66).Value Then
            k = k + 1
    ElseIf Cells(r, 67).Value <> Cells(r + 1, 67).Value And Cells(r, 67).Value <> "" Then
            Rows(k & ":" & r - 1).Rows.Group
            k = r + 1

    End If

Next CellId
'




Sheets("Category_Sales").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=6
Sheets("Category_Sales").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=5
Sheets("Category_Sales").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=4
Sheets("Category_Sales").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
Sheets("Category_Sales").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
Sheets("Category_Sales").Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
'



End Sub

Sub Load_Data()


Sheets("Data_Load").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Sheets("Headers").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Range("A24").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False



End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I cannot send you this report since it contains real prod data.

Comment: In LineColor, you declare and set a value for k...but you never use it.  Removing the Selects, and qualifying your references will help speed it up a tad.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: @Rdster This sounds more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo Very true, but Ballsy26 produced a much better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some easy changes to make

**Disable Stuff**

copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391786/effect-of-screen-updating

```
Sub YourSub()
    On Error GoTo EH

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Code here

    CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Do error handling
    GoTo CleanUp
End Sub
```

**Removing .select**

In `Load_Data` you use a few unnecessary selections, these slow down code

```
Sheets("Data_Load").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

these can be changed to remove some unnecessary parts

```
Sheets("Data_Load").Range("A2").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

in general where you use `.select` followed by `selection.` you can remove the `.select` and `selection.` and join the 2 parts together

```
Columns("BL:BP").Select 'kasowanie pól z GMH
Selection.Delete
```

becomes

```
Columns("BL:BP").Delete 'kasowanie pól z GMH
```

**Use With ... End With**

here you use the full statement to get to the same pivot table each time

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("CoreElementCode").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("CategoryCode").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("SubcategoryCode").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("BMCCode").Orientation = xlHidden
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesCategory").PivotFields("ProductID").Orientation = xlHidden
```

this can be simplified to, including using the actual sheet name

```
With Sheets("Category_Sales").PivotTables("SalesCategory")
    .PivotFields("CoreElementCode").Orientation = xlHidden
    .PivotFields("CategoryCode").Orientation = xlHidden
    .PivotFields("SubcategoryCode").Orientation = xlHidden
    .PivotFields("BMCCode").Orientation = xlHidden
    .PivotFields("ProductID").Orientation = xlHidden
End With
```